# What element do you target to click a checkbox with selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, click

I am trying to click on a checkbox on a website using selenium webdriver. The HTML for the checkbox is this following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="registrationForm:certIndCB" id="registrationForm:certIndCB" value="true" onclick="continueAction();">
```

I tried the following codes:

```
# first code
driver_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
cert_info = driver_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'registrationForm:certIndCB')))
cert_info.click()
# second code
cert_info = driver.find_element(By.ID,'registrationForm:certIndCB')
cert_info.click()
# third code
cert_info = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='registrationForm:certIndCB']")
cert_info.click()
```

But all have returned an error. The first code received a timeout error and the other two send this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 143
    139 time.sleep(3)
    141 # driver_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    142 # cert_info = driver_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'registrationForm:certIndCB')))
--> 143 cert_info = driver.find_element(By.ID,'registrationForm:certIndCB')
    144 cert_info.click()
    145 wait
```

I refreshed the page and made sure the elements were not flexing and the `id` stays as `registrationForm:certIndCB`. I was under the impression `id` was the better of the elements to select for a `.click()`. Does anyone might know why it cannot find the element despite it appearing when I inspect element?

**UPDATE**

So, I realized the website opened a new window which is where my element is located. While, I hoped this would be the issue but it still does not read the element. I used this code to cycle to the correct page:

```
for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
    driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
    if "name" in driver.title:
        break
```

However, this still could not find the element. In `inspect element` tried to use right-click and then selected `Copy` and used the `Copy Xpath / Copy Full Xpath` option, but my program says it cannot find the element.

I also double checked and it is *not* inside an iFrame.

If anyone has an insights, I am confused on why it would not detect the element. Would there be ways for the site to prevent `selenium` from being able to select the elements? The site is accessed by a user/pswd so I cannot bypass the element by using a URL that skips the step (this step also verifies certain information so it is my desire to perform this step).

Comment: Check if the desired element is within an `IFRAME`?

Comment: Full transparency: I had to look up what iframe was and from the research I did it is not appear to be within one. I checked the page source manually, and there was not a iframe tag. If that was the incorrect way to check let me know, I saw you could do a JavaScript code to check but I know nothing about JavaScript lang or environments

Comment: Check the answer below to know how you can use `JS` to click on a web element.

Answer (score 1):

See below code for clicking a web element using `JavaScript` in python selenium:

```
time.sleep(5)
radioButton = driver.find_element(By.ID,'registrationForm:certIndCB')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", radioButton )
```

Comment: So I received this error: `TypeError: Object of type Javascript is not JSON serializable` and it got hit on this line: `--> 144 Javascript(driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", radioButton ))`. The `Javascript()` function was downloaded from this lib: `from IPython.display import Javascript`. Any insight?

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
(By.ID,'registrationForm:certIndCB')
```

Selenium converts it to a CSS selector

```
#registrationForm:certIndCB
```

and CSS selectors don't like ":"s in IDs. I've run into this issue before. I found that converting it to a different syntax of CSS selector worked for me.

```
[id="registrationForm:certIndCB"]
```

Below is your original code with a proper wait updated with the new CSS selector.

```
driver_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
cert_info = driver_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[id="registrationForm:certIndCB"]')))
cert_info.click()
```